# Взаимодействие ссылок и указателей

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

Если в функцию, принимающую `int&`, передать `*p`, где `p` - указатель на `int`, то функция будет работать с исходными данными, находящимися по этому адресу, или с их копией?

Comment: а чем "данные лежащие по адресу p" (то есть данные, которые находятся по адресу, который записан в p) будут отличаться от оригинала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С оригиналом по адресу `p`. Вы могли легко набросать пару строк и убедиться в этом:

```
void f(int&i)
{
    ++i;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int x = 5;
    int * p = &x;
    f(*p);
    cout << x << endl;
}
```